# Apache jmeter - parsing json limit on size

Tags: json, jmeter

Is there a limit on the size of a json that can be parsed by jmeter?

I am trying to use a json in my jmeter initialization script. The size of json is quite huge. I see that if i truncate the json, the parsing is error-free. But for the original size i get an error.

Rest assured, the json itself is proper, as i have tested in other javascript parsers.

Update: Since it is established that there *indeed* is a limit, the question is if there is a way to work-around the limit?

Comment: your finding suggest there is such a limit.

Comment: How are you parsing json? Are you using java code in Beanshell Sampler/PostProcessor e.g. for this for this? What is the error you are getting? What's in jmeter.log? What is the size of your json response?

Comment: hey @AliesBelik, thanks for your suggestion, i checked jmeter.log: `jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor: Problem in BSF script org.apache.bsf.BSFException: JavaScript Error: Encountered code generation error while compiling script: generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.`

Comment: The only thing I can possibly advise is try to use Beanshell PreProcessor instead with beanshell (=java) code to parse your json+ any json-processing library (e.g. [json-rpc-1.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/metaparadigm/json-rpc/1.0/json-rpc-1.0.jar)) added to jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

The only work-around I could make work was to split the js into multiple files, the following way:

```
file1.js: vars.putObject('huge_json', {"foo" : [...], "bar" : {...}});
file2.js: vars.getObject('huge_json').foo.push({"foo_child" : {...}});
...
final_file: var hugeJson = vars.getObject('huge_json');
```